# Firefox при печати не разбивает документ на страницы

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование

Добрый день. На одном из сайтов которые используют функцию window.print() столкнулся с проблемой - Firefox весь контент оставляет на первой странице. В Chrome, например, документ разбивается нормально.
CSS-стили "page-break-..." не работают.

[image: Page print-version - Chrome and Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Выяснил какой блок не разбивается (общий wrapper страницы).
Как оказалось, Firefox не умеет разбивать блок со стилем "display: flex;" на страницы при печати.
Решилось добавлением для @media print стиля "display: block"